# Can you make html files not show '.html' in the url?

Tags: html

Is there a way to show page name only in the url minus the '.html' part of it?
for example: 
www.website.com/about-us.html  to look like -> www.website.com/about-us

also have the trailing / work too to make it look like www.website.com/about-us/

Comment: I see those work but what about having a trailing / at the end?
like www.website.com/about-us/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but this is a feature of your web server rather than HTML itself.

You'll need to consult the docs for the web server that you're using (probably Apache or Nginx).

If you're not administrating your own server, you may not have permission to do this.  Ask your admin.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?[^/]+/?$ /%{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

This is assuming you are using an Apache web server and not IIS.  If you are using Apache, you can create a file called ".htaccess" with my code above and put it into the site's directory in which you want Apache to rewrite the names.